# What does the mass term mean in the unit of inductance called the Henry?

Tags: inductance

Reduced to base SI units, one henry is the equivalent of one kilogram meter squared per second squared per ampere squared (kg m<sup>2</sup> s<sup>-2</sup> A<sup>-2</sup>).

This does not look like the standard F = ma formula for a force but there is a mass term.  What does the mass term represent?  I am trying to understand how the units gel together.

Comment: Does it help to think of it as \$\frac{J}{A^2}\$?

Comment: you mean joule over ampere squared?

Comment: Remember that all derived units, such as inductance, can eventually be reduced to the basic units of length, mass and time.

Comment: this is a very interesting topic but I have to admit I would love to know more because I do not understand how this can be. ...perhaps a small example?

Comment: You could say that \$1\:J =1\: V \:A \:s\$, but it's also \$1\: kg\: m^2 \:s^{-2}\$. Just use the appropriate units for the task at hand.

Comment: Magnetic charge (the Weber) is a measure of angular momentum (Joule-s) per Coulomb; and magnetic charge per amp is the Henry. Magnetic moment and angular momentum are related. Revolving charged particles have both mass and charge and magnetic moment and angular momentum both increase with the rate. (The ratio of these is the gyromagnetic ratio. Note there is also a difference in the angular momentum of electron spin and the angular momentum of the electron in an atomic orbit, so to speak.)

Comment: Inductance is volts x time divided by current. Do you know the SI unit for volts?

Comment: great comments ...i am out of the woods and the units work Ok  ...very knowledgeable people on site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let \$P\$ be power in watts, \$I\$ be current in amps, \$W\$ be work in Joules,

\$A\$ Acceleration in meters per \$\text{second}^2\$ \$D\$ distance in meters, \$M\$ Mass in kg.

\$T\$ Time in seconds, \$F\$ Force in newtons and \$V\$ voltage in volts.

We know \$ P = V \cdot I\$ so \$V = \dfrac{P}{I}\$.

Basic physics should tell you Power is Work divided by time \$P = \dfrac{W}{T}\$.

Work is Force times distance \$W = F \cdot D\$

Force is mass times Acceleration \$F = M \cdot A\$.

Putting all this together we see.

\$ V = \dfrac{P}{I} = \dfrac{W}{I \cdot T} = \dfrac{F \cdot D}{I \cdot T} = \dfrac{M \cdot A \cdot D}{I \cdot T} = \dfrac{M \cdot D \cdot D}{I \cdot T \cdot T^2} = \dfrac{M \cdot D^2}{I \cdot T^3}\$

Using standard SI units the volt is therefore \$\dfrac{\mathrm{kg} \cdot \mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{A} \cdot \mathrm{s}^3}\$

Now we know \$ V = L \cdot \dfrac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}t}\$ Now dimensionally \$ L = \dfrac{\text{volts}}{\text{amps}} \cdot \text{time}\$

Using standard SI units the henry is therefore \$\dfrac{\mathrm{kg} \cdot \mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{A} \cdot \mathrm{s}^3} \cdot \dfrac{\text{s}}{\text{A}} = \dfrac{\mathrm{kg} \cdot \mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{A}^2 \cdot \mathrm{s}^2}\$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_(unit)    ..I found this in Wiki...you mean all these  will work out the same in term of dimensions of units ?